# Does Intel MKL support Armadilo, Eigen or Biltz++?

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-algebra, multidimensional-array

I mean: can it define some array like Blitz++ does (I am looking for similar simple syntax, no need to be exactly  the same.):

```
Array<double, 3> A(NX,NY,NZ)
```

Thanks.

I heard that the Armadilo, Eigen, Boost and Biltz++ among the best choice for scientific computing. Can these library use together with intel MKL? Do they need to be used together with Intel MKL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you checked out the following Knowledge Base article about MKL Compatibility for 3rd party libraries?

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-and-third-party-applications-how-to-use-them-together

Here the MKL Link Line Advisor can help too.

Also take a look at this article for Eigen

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html

Per your question >> Do they need to be used together with Intel MKL?

Yes. Even the documentation for these packages say so. Example: Armadillo site: “Various matrix decompositions are provided through optional integration with LAPACK, or one of its high performance drop-in replacements (such as the multi-threaded MKL or ACML libraries).”

Comment: Armadillo's [FAQ page](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#dependencies) has further info on linking with MKL, ACML, OpenBlas, etc.